# How to get the max of row number for a table in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, row-number

## Heading

`MAX(ROW_NUMBER)` does not work in `teradata`. But in cases where where it is required to implement the same scenario, how to achieve that?

Suppose my base table looks like this--

```
Month  Prev_Sport  Curr_Sport 
JAN     REST        CRICKET
JAN     CRICKET     RUGBY
FEB     REST        SKATING
FEB     SKATING     RAFTING
MAR     REST        RACING
MAR     RACING      GLIDING
```

The output table should be like--

```
Month   First_Sport    Last_Sport
JAN      CRICKET        RUGBY
FEB      SKATING        RAFTING
MAR      RACING         GLIDING
```

Here we can get the desired `Last_Sport` column in output if we create `rownumber` on main table and fetch the data based on the `max(rownumber)`. But the same does not work in `teradata`.

Is there any alternative solution for that?

Comment: I don't see how `row_number()` is related to your example, which seems to show a linked list.  If you want to use `row_number()`, you need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: I don't know teradata so may be way off but an alternative to `MAX(ID)` is `select top (1) ID from MyTable order by ID desc` if that helps at all

Comment: The above example is a prototype only. Actually there will be around 100 rows for each month and in output there will be one record for each month--For First_Sport column the data will be from Curr_Sport where Prev_Sport is 'REST' for a particular month. And for Last_Sport Column data will be from last record of Curr_Sport for a particular month. So for Last_Sport we need to create something like max(row_number)

Comment: If you've gotten your row_number() working, then you can use `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER...`.  Post your query with row_number in it, and I'm sure we can get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existing DBMS allows a MAX(ROW_NUMBER).

You didn't show how the ROW_NUMBER is calculated, but when you want the MAX of it you can simply reverse the ORDER and then

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY .... DESC) = 1
```